# what is wrong with this if i delete rgba background-image appear but if i write it background image gone

Tags: css

```
   .mainheder {    
     background-image: rgba(0,0,0,0.7), url(imgs/slider-01.jpg);
     background-size: cover;## Heading ##
     height: 100vh;
              }**strong text**
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, the question as asked is unclear-- it is hard to understand what is expected and what is actually happening.  Please review [ask] and see if it can be written more clearly-- in this way the community can provide you with the best assistance possible.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

use background property, and it use linear gradient rather than rgba,
follow this article for more.
[link to article](https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/)

```
enter code here

.mainheder {    
 background: 
  linear-gradient(
  rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
  rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
),
 url(imgs/slider-01.jpg);
 background-size: cover;## Heading ##
 height: 100vh;
          }**strong text*
```